# SQLite importing csv file

Tags: sqlite

I am using SQLite and I can't import this csv file for some reason. I ran cmd first then entered SQLite.

---

my input in cmd:

```
cd C:\Users\Fries\Desktop\SQLite

sqlite3

.mode csv

.import C:\Users\Fries\Desktop\city.csv cities

.schema cities
```

---

I am using this tutorial. http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-import-csv/
for some reason I can't open the csv

[image]

I am new to dbms and sqlite seems to be a super simple one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the feedback in the error message, it looks like the backslashes need to be escaped.  I would first try this:

```
sqlite> .import C:/Users/Fries/Desktop/city.csv
```

The following might also work, using escaped backslashes:

```
sqlite> .import C:\\Users\\Fries\\Desktop\\city.csv
```